# Can a AWS Lambda function work directly with files on s3 or is moving to /tmp/ needed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to write an AWS lambda function in Python to collect a bunch of csv files from an s3 bucket, concatenate them, drop the duplicates and write the result back to s3. The files I want to read are stored with a prefix/in a folder on s3. Currently I am trying to read the files one by one using the following apporach:

```
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket')
#getting all objects in the bucket in a list
for obj in resp['Contents']:
    keys.append(obj['Key'])
#filtering those that are parsed entries
files = [k[6:] for k in keys if 'links/links' in k]
#reading into combined list
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        links = links + list(reader)
```

Currently I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'links2020-02-27 14:59:49.933074.csv'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 21, in concatenatelinks\n    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:\n"
  ]
}
```

In an earlier version, I didn't slice the filenames, which caused the same error. So do I need to load all files into /tmp/ with something like
`s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/' + str(filename), bucket, 'fusedlinks/' + str(filename))` to make them accessible to the lamda function or is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: no. you need to download them

Comment: You don't need to download them to disk, if that's what you're asking. It might make life simpler to do so, assuming you don't exceed the /tmp diskspace limit, but you can stream the S3 object contents into the memory of the Lambda, do whatever manipulation is required in memory, then stream the resulting data back to a new object in S3.

Comment: I loaded them all to disk. Wouldn't that also be beneficial as I could then decrease the memory provided to the function? In the end that would be the billable part of it, right? (I am still within free tier)

Answer (score 3):

From the error it seems that filename convention is incorrect: `links2020-02-27 14:59:49.933074.csv`. You probably need to escape the "**whitespace**" while reading the file through boto3 client.

But to read the file there are two options, I personally prefer Option 2 (but depends on memory usage):

1. **One to use filesystem as /tmp**

You can refer the sample example as mentioned on [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python)

Also AWS Lambda provides /tmp size of 512 MB at the moment, you will need to find a different solution if total size of all files is more than 512 MB. Refer [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

2. **Second option is to use In-memory buffer**.
   You can use: Python's [BytesIo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). Example below:

```py
    def load_from_s3(bucket, path):
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        with BytesIO() as data:
            s3_resource.Bucket(bucket).download_fileobj(path, data)
            data.seek(0)
            # Do something with your data in file
```

Comment: Yes, these are the two way. (1) has an upper limit of 512MB, and (2) has a limit constrained by your memorySize allocated to the function.